# Pygame | blited image keeps jumping all over the place

Tags: python, class, pygame

Hi guys I was wondering if I could get a bit of help with this. I'm learning Classes in python and trying to incorporate it into my current project for uni.

So below is the code for the class as-well as some variables used by it

```
class Asteroid():
    def __init__(self, char, startX, startY):
        self.char = char
        self.startX = startX
        self.startY = startY
        self.drawChar()

    def drawChar (self):
        self.space = pygame.image.load (self.char)
        self.space = self.space.convert_alpha()
        gameDisplay.blit(self.space,
            (random.randint(0,display_width),
            random.randint(0,display_height)))
```

Basically this class incorporates all the data I need to load in 'Asteroids'.

below is part of the main code where the class is actually being used:

```
Asteroid(random.choice(asteroid),200,300 )
```

Also below is the code for the variable `asteroid`:

```
asteroid = [
    'Sprites/Asteroid1.png',
    'Sprites/Asteroid2.png',
    'Sprites/Asteroid3.png']
```

So the actual problem that occurs is when I run the code the asteroids are blited unto the surface but they're jumping all over the place. Not only that but different asteroids are being blited rather than one chosen asteroid. Why is this occuring?

On a side note the asteroid also have a white background, I tried converting them but that doesn't help.

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote. It's a legitimate question, even if it is a noobish one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you tell it to. The code

```
gameDisplay.blit(self.space,
            (random.randint(0,display_width),
             random.randint(0,display_height)))
```

literally says "blit the image onto the display at a random location." Specifically, `random.randint(0,...)` picks random positions from zero to the screen size.

Keep in mind that this display code gets called every time the screen needs to be updated, not just when you start the game. To display at static coordinates, make the coordinates static:

```
gameDisplay.blit(self.space, (self.startX, self.startY))
```

Comment: wow, I was not aware of this. Sorry if I look dumb, still looking at the concepts of Class. Any ideas about my image with white backgrounds?

Comment: If this answer helps you, please select it. The white background is a completely separate issue, so I recommend that you ask a separate question for that.